# Adding client scripts for the server side event GridView.OnPageIndexChanging

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Is there a matching client side event that is fired before or after `OnPageIndexChanging` is raised?

Such as the `OnClientClick`, I would like to append a script when the paging numbers / arrows are clicked.

Is it possible, of so; how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are speaking of the DataGrid/GridView component. There is no such built-in even but you can easily hook a JavaScript event handler for the pager links. Here is an example using jQuery:

```
$('#GridView1 td table a').live('click', function() { 
    var pagerLink = this;
})
```

Comment: Allright, but the pager uses some other built in javascript methods to do postbacking and stuff, is it possible to run some event with jquery After that?

Comment: You can execute any code within the event handler. Perhaps I could be more specific if you provide more info as to what should happen when the user clicks the pager.